# Temporary failure Archlinux Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, archlinux

I use a custom dockerfile for my container and i got this error when i try to up my container with `docker-compose up -d`

```
Step 4/14 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  libzip-dev wget curl nodejs npm
 ---> Running in 6007160b4c25
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
```

i test with a dns in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{ "dns" : ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]}
```

but that doesn't work

Comment: That seems like it's an error in your network setup, possibly as the error suggests something that will resolve itself.  I don't think there's anything in your code you could change to address this.

Comment: On ubuntu i use docker engine, that was not present on Arch ... Maybe it's a part of a probleme ?